# Get Field Based on FK

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I didn't quite know how to word my issue, so I apologize for the odd title.  I currently have two MySQL tables, business and users that look like the following respectively:

```
+-------------+----------+
| business_id | owner_id |
|      1      |    1     |
|      2      |    3     |
+-------------+----------+

+---------+-------------+----------------+
| user_id | business_id |      email     |
|    1    |      1      |  a@domain.com  |
|    2    |      1      |  b@domain.com  |
|    3    |      2      |  c@domain.com  |
+---------+-------------+----------------+
```

Right now, I need to get the email of the user where the `business_id` field in the `user` table matches that of the `owner_id` in the `business` table and I will always have the user_id (but it might not necessarily be the owner).  To demonstrate what I mean, I can achieve what I want through this mess of a code:

```
SELECT
    `email`
FROM
    `user`
WHERE
    `user_id` =(
    SELECT
        `owner_id`
    FROM
        `business`
    WHERE
        `business_id` =(
        SELECT
            `business_id`
        FROM
            `user`
        WHERE
            `user_id` = :user_id
    )
)
```

So if I were to pass the a value of 1 or 2 for the `user_id` parameter, it would return `a@domain.com` and if I passed a value of 3 it would return `c@domain.com`.

I just feel as thought there is a better way!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insead of subqueries you can use joins to achieve the same result by joining the `user` table twice with different aliases:

```
select u2.email
from user u1
inner join business b on u1.business_id=b.business_id
inner join user u2 on b.owner_id=u2.user_id
where u1.user_id=...
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/329561/5)

Comment: Whenever I attempted to join the user table like in your suggestion, it is returning both of the owner's emails rather than the owner's email where the business_id's match that of the id passed in the parameter.

Comment: Grr, typo- which you could have spotted yourself in the 1st on clause u1.business_id=u1.business_id - one of the tables should be b instead of u1

Comment: @Shadow - Thank you, that was an oversight on my part (I shouldn't've been in a rush).

Comment: @Barmar - Yes, now it does. There was a typo that he corrected just prior to your comment.